# Where to buy long-fit short sleeved t-shirts in Bangkok in 200≤Baht?

Tags: thailand, clothing

I usually buy [long-fit](https://th.hm.com/t-shirt-long-fit-0598755014001.html) short sleeved t-shirts, black and plain ("[aniconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniconism)"), in European medium size at different H&M branches in Bangkok; I don't recall finding such shirts in any other shop in malls or in any market.

As I recall, it always cost me 400 ("399") Baht in H&M and this always felt to me like a rip off because I bet the shirt (production, transportation and sorting) doesn't cost H&M more than 50 Baht to perhaps be exaggerating, and because if I buy groceries at Klong Toey market (which is Bangkok's largest wholesaling food bazzar), I could pay the same price for about 7.5 kilos of food which could last for at about 3 weeks.

Where can one buy long-fit short sleeved t-shirts in Bangkok, preferably in European sizes, in less than or equal to 200 Baht?

### Update for Scott Earle

[image]

Comment: I ask the down voter to explain her or his down vote as this would be helpful - if someone fear I would "troll back" for doing so, I suggest to remove this fear from mind.

Comment: If it was the wrong 2000 instead 200 or minor discrepancy between the heading question and the final question --- these are now, in principle, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem a little strange that the OP is familiar with places like Khlong Toey food market (cheapest chicken market in ... the world?), but has not heard of either Platinum or Pratunam markets. These are large clothes markets in the centre of town not far from Central World.

Platinum is an older-style mall that sells clothes mostly to Thai teenagers, and they have a decent selection of everything. Pratunam market is more of a wholesale clothes market, and people come from all over South East Asia to buy clothes wholesale for export. Locals also go there to pick up cheap clothes.

Another place to find wholesale clothes is Bo Bae (โบ๊เบ๊) market towards the old town from Rama I road (go along Rama I and keep going until you cross the bridge that goes over the khlong - it's in there on the right).

Comment: Oh gosh, I am a vegetarian near to vegan for about 8 years (chicken market) ; I already searched desperately, twice in Platinum ; I didn't find anything suiting in Pratunam markets (I did find the best ever short pants I bought there - no exaggeration ; best in design and price ever). I should do one more check in Pratunam market (especially the ally one, in front of Platinum) ; I plan to check Bo Bae (โบ๊เบ๊) --- thanks !!!

Comment: Bo Bae is next to Prince Palace hotel - can be tricky to find, but a taxi driver should(!) be able to get you there

Comment: Hello Scott; I humbly prefer to walk there from หมู่ บ้าน เสรี - I updated the question about a picture from Google maps that helps me understand why you said it could be tricky (where the gray dots are, is there no crossing?)

Comment: Bo Bae tower is worth a visit, if you don’t find anything of interest at the market :)